# Cluster won't start from jupyter tab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I can start a cluster with `ipcluster start -n number` but when I tried to start from the jupyter cluster tab, it does not seem to work:

in the terminal (with the `jupyter-notebook` command output), I only see:

`[I 12:15:38.008 NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/me/.ipython/profile_default'`

and

`from ipyparallel import Client
rc = Client()
rc.ids`

return an empty list.

I would like to start the cluster from the jupyter tab. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues, and solved it by installing ipyparallel from the developing version:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel
$ cd ipyparallel
$ pip install -U .
```

Then to enable the notebook extension:

```
$ ipcluster nbextension enable --user
```

I am using the `--user` parameter because I am working on a virtual environment without `sudo` privileges. I also made sure that I had the latest jupyter notebook versions using `pip`. `pip install -U jupyter` and `pip install -U notebook`.

My current versions are:

- Python 2.7.10
- jupyter 4.4.0
- jupyter notebook 5.4.1
- ipyparallel 6.2.0.dev